# What are the rules for virtual function lookup?

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual-functions

```
#include <iostream>
class base
{
    public:
    virtual void print (int a)
    {   
        std::cout << "a: " << a << " base\n";
    }   
    virtual void print (int a, int b)
    {   
        std::cout << "base\n";
    }   
};

class derived : public base
{
    public:
    virtual void print (double d)
    {   
        std::cout << "derived\n";
    }   
};

int main ()
{
    int i = 10; 
    double d = 10000.0;
    base *b = new derived (); 
    b->print (i, i); 
    b->print (d);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this function is:

```
base
a: 10000 base
```

- Why `b->print (d)` don't invoke the derived class implementation and
  performs static cast on `'d'` to provide a match with base class
  implementation ?
- What rule is applied here during virtual function lookup ?

Comment: You're working with the type base, not derived. It doesn't have a function which takes a double, so it's casting to int to find the best match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`derived::print` does not override any member function in `base`.  It is declared as having a single parameter of type `double` but the two virtual member functions named `print` in `base` are declared as having one and two parameters of type `int`.

When you use `b->print(d)`, only member functions in `base` are considered during overload resolution, so only `void base::print(int)` and `void base::print(int, int)` are considered.  `void derived::print(double)` can't be found because the compiler has no idea that `b` points to a `derived` object.

If `derived` were to override one of the two `print` functions declared as virtual member functions in `base`, then that override would be called at runtime.

(On a somewhat related note, `derived::print` hides the two `base::print` member functions, so if you were to try to use one of the base class `print` functions, e.g., `derived().print(1, 1)`, it would fail.  You would need to use a using declaration to make those member functions available during name lookup.)

Answer (score 1):

Overload resolution happens at compile time. Overrides happen at run time.

Therefore, the overload resolution of `b->print(d);` happens first. This selects `Base::print(int)` because it's the only one-argument `print`.

At runtime, `b` points to a `Derived` object that has no override for `Base::print(int)`. Therefore, `Base::print(int)` is still called.

Answer (score 0):

Because double can be automatically converted to an int in the first definition it sees (in the base class)

See `explicit` keyword or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)